# How is it possible to style button component with different styles in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and wanted to create a calculator in React as a practice project. I decided to use CSS modules to style my components. Here is the look of the calculator I want to create

[image]

As you can see from the photo of the calculator, there are several buttons and some of them have different width and colors. What I wanted to do is to create ONE button component and reuse it for each button in the calculator. Please can you give a hint about what I can do to theme with CSS modules? Guys, I am kindly asking that you show the right direction not asking you to create that project for me or something like that. I hope you got my point.

Comment: what seems to be a problem though ? You create different css styles and  apply them as needed to buttons that require those styles. Nothing different from regular css, html and js

Comment: @Noob, thanks for your kind reply, I did research and it is said that something called  Theming should be used. Is that correct?

Comment: it can be done in different ways, but it can be done in a simple way described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with@Noob, Theming would just over complicate the project. You probably just need to create regular class style for the button and apply to the component Button one by one.

```
<Button className={styles.number}>1</Button>
<Button className={styles.operator}>+</Button>
```